# MySQL query performance issue with OR operator and subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I want to select all contracts that has been modified after a certain time and also if the associated tables have been modified:

```
select *
from Contracts
    join OriginalContracts OContracts on (Contracts.OriginalContract = OContracts.OID)  
    join ContractAccessories CAccessories on (Contracts.Oid = CAccessories.Contract)
where 
    Contracts.LastChanged > '2023-05-16 10:00:00'
    or OContracts.LastChanged > '2023-05-16 10:00:00'
    or CAccessories.LastChanged > '2023-05-16 10:00:00'
```

My problem is that the query is very slow (300 ms).

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | key | key_len | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | CAccessories |  | ALL |  |  | 4230 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | Contracts |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | 4 | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | OContracts |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | 4 | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |

I have added indexes on all keys and LastChanged.

I have tried by using subqueries:

```
select *
from Contracts Contracts  
where 
    Contracts.OID in (select contract from ContractAccessories where LastChanged > '2023-05-15 19:00:00' union select contract from OriginalContracts where LastChanged > '2023-05-15 19:00:00' union select Oid as contract from Contracts where LastChanged > '2023-05-15 19:00:00')
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | Contracts |  | ALL |  |  | 938029 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ContractAccessories |  | ref | 5 | func | 1 | 2.69 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT UNION | OriginalContracts |  | ref | 5 | func | 1 | 3.78 | Using where |
| 4 | DEPENDENT UNION | Contracts |  | eq_ref | 4 | func | 1 | 5.00 | Using where |
|  | UNION RESULT | <union2,3,4> |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | Using temporary |

This call is also very slow. If I execute the subquery in a separate call, this call is fast. If I paste the result from the subquery into to query and execute this, it is also fast. Can anyone explain this and also have a solution to?

Comment: Hi - why do you think 300ms is slow, how fast are you expecting this to run? Does this 300ms include network latency?

Comment: Hi - It includes network latency but the call is very central and will be called many times. Since the subquery can be executed fast and the “outer” query can be executed fast just with the result from the subquery, then I think there must be a way to do it.

Comment: Query does not seem to be using LastChanged indexes by looking at you 'Extra' column from ANALYZE. Did you try to run EXPLAIN ANALYZE, there is probably table scan? 
One blind guess, try something like with yourUnionId AS (...) select * from Contracts where Contracts.OID IN (select id from yourUnionIds)

Comment: Is "Accessories" a type of contract?  Can't you have a single table for all Contracts?  That would make the query simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

By putting a select around the subqueries like below solves the performance problem.

```
select *
from Contracts Contracts  
where 
    Contracts.OID in
(SELECT contract
FROM
(
    SELECT contract FROM ContractAccessories WHERE LastChanged > '2023-05-15 19:00:00'
    UNION
    SELECT contract FROM OriginalContracts WHERE LastChanged > '2023-05-15 19:00:00'
    UNION
    SELECT Oid AS contract FROM Contracts WHERE LastChanged > '2023-05-15 19:00:00'
) AS subquery);
```

Now the call is blazing fast :-)